# Proof Cantor set and its complement

Tags: cantor-set

I have to prove that between any two points of the Cantor set there exists an interval contained entirely in the complement of the Cantor set.

How do you prove this given only the fact that its uncountable and its cardinality is c? I'm not allowed to prove it using self similar properties.

Is a proof by induction possible?

Comment: Obviously you cannot just argue using that the Cantor set has size $\mathfrak c$. Use the definition of the set. And yes, it is possible to give what is essentially an inductive argument. There are other ways as well.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show me how to stary the the argument?

Comment: I would start by writing down a specific definition of the Cantor set.

Comment: It would depend on what definition you are using for the cantor set. But if you write the two numbers in base $3$ using only $0$ and $2$, then the first digit where they differ has have one with $0$ and the other with $2$. The interval between them is the interval where there is a $1$ in this place and neither all zeros or all twos after, which is an open interval $$\left(a3^{-n}+3^{-n-1},a3^{-n}+2\cdot 3^{-n-1}\right)$$ where $a3^{-n}$ are the common first $n$ digits.